# SQL Server 2008: SELECT * INTO TMP from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wish to do the following:

```
select * into tmptbl from sometable
```

EXCEPT 'sometable' is a stored procedure that returns a result set AND editing the stored procedure to suit my goal is not an option. ALSO i may or may not know the columns and types of what the procedure returns.

Basically i am looking for a proper way of doing this:

select * into tmptbl from exec someSP

Is this even possible, if so, how?

Comment: So you're turning the results of a stored procedure into a Temp Table?

Comment: yes, that is what i wish to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it is possible with a loopback query like this

```
SELECT * INTO #tmptbl 
    FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;'
   ,'set fmtonly off exec DatabaseName.dbo.someSP')
```

More example here: [Store The Output Of A Stored Procedure In A Table Without Creating A Table](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Store_The_Output_Of_A_Stored_Procedure_In_A_Table_Without_Creating_A_Table)

Be aware that this has to be turned on first, see here: [How to enable xp_cmdshell and Ad Hoc Distributed Queries on SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-enable-xp_cmdshell-on-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: no good, 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' are not enabled and i am not an admin.

Comment: That is the only way I know of

Comment: This works however this has to be done first on a default installation:

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO;

Ugly but it works, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, see also here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-enable-xp_cmdshell-on-sql-server-2005